# Iterate excel value and match with txt file value

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to read read excel cell value and then try to match excel cell value with the value present in the txt file.

Issue is when following code execute then it only matches 1675683811 value from excel cell with 1675683811 value from DATA.txt and then for other three values it is not matching. How can I match all four values with DATA.txt file.

In one particular excel cell value look like as below:

```
String meid = "1675683811,2002199221,3893245956,9184020971";
```

And in the txt file value looks like as below:

```
"1675683811","590483002",
"2002199221","876015525",
"3893245956","502139683",
"9184020971","1029595777",
```

Following are my code:

```
static int i = "";
File objFile = new File("C:\\DATA.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(objFile));
String st;

String[] memid =meid.split(",");
int matchValue = 0;

for(i = 0;i<memid.length;i++){                  
    matchValue = 0;
    System.out.println("Memberid is :"+memid[i]);

    while ((st = br.readLine()) != null){
        if (st.toString().contains(memid[i].toString())){
            matchValue++;   
        } else {

        } 
    }
    if (matchValue != 0) {
        objReport.setValidationMessageInReport("PASS" , memid[i] + " text Value is Matched");   
    } else {
        //                  continue;
        objReport.setValidationMessageInReport("FAIL" , memid[i] + " text Value is not Matched");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've  trying read the file inside the `for` loop. Once the file is read/head reaches the end of the file , `BufferedReader` always returns null. ie, after first iteration of `for` (`i>=1`) loop the while loop always returns `null`. I'd read the file outside `for` loop, store it in an array and check if your excel row element is `contains`ed that string.

Some thing like :

```
  int i = 0;
  File objFile = new File("C:\\DATA.txt");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(objFile));
  String st;
  String strMemId = "1675683811,2002199221,3893245956,9184020972";
  String[] memid =strMemId.split(",");
  int matchValue = 0;
  String fromFile = "";
  while ((st = br.readLine()) != null)
  {
      fromFile += st;

  }
  for(i = 0;i<memid.length;i++)
  {
      matchValue = 0;

      if (fromFile.contains(memid[i].toString())){
          matchValue++;   
      }
      System.out.println("Memberid is :"+memid[i]);


      if (matchValue != 0) {
           objReport.setValidationMessageInReport("PASS" , memid[i] + " text Value is Matched");      
      } else {
          //                  continue;
          objReport.setValidationMessageInReport("FAIL" , memid[i] + " text Value is not Matched");
      }
  }
  br.close();
```

Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

In your inner `while` loop you read from the file line by line until you reach the end of file and once you done that nothing more will be read so when the outer `for` reaches the `while` loop a second (and third and so forth) time `br.readLine()` will always return null.

I would suggest you change place on your loops, outer loop reads the next line from the file and inside you do the matching against the excel array.

Answer (score 0):

When you are reading the file through buffered reader in the first iteration of for loop using while, you end up consuming the entire file. It points to the end of file... so in the next iteration it is equal to null and it fails at the first pass of while loop.

```
while ((st = br.readLine()) != null){ // in the first iteration it finished reading the file
        if (st.toString().contains(memid[i].toString())){
            matchValue++;   
        } else {

        }
```

Here is what you need to do

```
static int i = "";
File objFile = new File("C:\\DATA.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(objFile));
String st;
String str="";
while ((st = br.readLine()) != null){
        str+=st;
    }

String[] memid =meid.split(",");

for(i = 0;i<memid.length;i++){                  
    matchValue = 0;
    System.out.println("Memberid is :"+memid[i]);


    if (str.contains(memid[i].toString())) {
        objReport.setValidationMessageInReport("PASS" , memid[i] + " text Value is Matched");   
    } else {
        //                  continue;
        objReport.setValidationMessageInReport("FAIL" , memid[i] + " text Value is not Matched");
    }
}
```